# Default property attribute in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, attributes

I have below mentioned property in my interface file

```
@property NSString *stringObject;
@property NSMutableString *anotherStringObject;
@property NSArray *array;
@property NSMutableArray *anotherarray;
@property NSNumber *number;
@property NSDictionary *dictionary;
@property NSMutableDictionary *anotherDictionary;

@property NSInteger myInteger;
@property int intValue;
@property BOOL boolValue;
@property CGFloat floatValue;
```

As i have not explicitly mentioned any attribute here, So i want to know what are the default attributes added by the compiler in this code.

**Note :** i have already read apple guide for this , only information i get there is by default it is `atomic` and `strong`. I want to know what other attributes added along with them.

Comment: The default/implicit values are atomic, readwrite, and assign.

Comment: assign for scalars, strong for objects.

Comment: ARC has changed to strong

Comment: @SandeepAgrawal, not for scalars.

Comment: @SandeepAgrawal, see my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mention you desired attributes ,then it will be :

For objects (NSObject , NSNumber , etc...) ==> readwrite/atomic/strong
For scalars  (NSIneger , BOOL , etc..)==> readwrite/atomic/assign

Comment: So if i have a block as a property , Is it going to be atomic & copy ?